# Windows Forms - add a new option in the Menu

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I want to add a "Dock" option here in the menu. I've seen a lot of posts on how to override those options but first, i have to add my new item there and after that, define the functionality for it.

Comment: Did you see any examples of such functionality?

Comment: Where you looking for something like [Manipulating the System Menu Using C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c9327/Manipulating-the-System-Menu-Using-C.htm)

Comment: @astander, it works fine, but if i try to set an MdiParent for this window, it docks as it should but the new property set on the menu vanishes and i can't undock it. strange thing. once set, how come it disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the ContextMenu property of the control you want to add the option to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254(v=vs.71).aspx is the MSDN article that explains how you can do this. it's doable both in the design mode and the code-behind.